# Twitter bootstrap nav-stacked css not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve the stackable effect as shown here:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

but somehow it is not working for me. Here is the link to a plunk that I have created:
http://plnkr.co/edit/LSR3ijKGiOIyrYAbHm7g
It just shows three list items one below another without the navbar effect of bootstrap.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="offset4 span4">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
                <li> Item1</li>
                <li> Item2</li>
                <li> Item3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I must be doing some blunder that something as simple as nav-stacked is not working. Would be glad and grateful if someone could point out my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the content in anchors, like so:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jpKAF/

Comment: Thanks! Isn't there any way to have simple text instead of anchor tags?

Comment: Not out of the box, as far as I know, you can probably make it work if you remove the ".nav-tabs.nav-stacked > li > a" to just ".nav-tabs.nav-tacked > li". I updated the JSFiddle with a CSS I pulled out of Bootstrap and just concatenated everything that was applied to the anchor and instead just applied it to the list item. Not sure if that is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks again. You have answered all of my questions. :)